# Extjs 4 - Namespaces in plugin like app

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have modular application that contains several modules/plugins, that can also run as standalone applications.

I dynamically register `module/plugin` controllers to main application and here is the problem in steps.

- My main app has A prefix - its controller" A.controller.AppController.
- My plugin has B prefix - its controller: B.controller.PortalController

Code of plugin controller:

```
 Ext.define('B.controller.PortalController', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
     views: [
         'portal.MapPanel',
         'administration.ConfigPanel',
         'administration.ConfigPanelWrapper'
     ],
     //stores:['Test'],
     init: function() {
         console.log('portal controller init');
         //console.log(this.getTestStore());
         this.control({

         });
     }
 });
```

The views register properly with B prefix, `Ext.Loader` loads `B.view.portal.MapPanel` but the store is not loaded.

If I specify `stores:['Test']` it tries to load `A.store.Test`, If I specify `test.Test` it does nothing (like error but ext-all-debug does not catch it) and if I specify `stores:['B.store.Test']` it loads it properly but now I have to use `getBStoreTestStore()` to get the store reference that will cause a lot of code changing.

How to make the controller to load stores with proper prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without override I think it is impossible. What is more for my views it should not work also!

All code from `ext-all-debug.js`

Controller loads classess properly using proper prefix using its own classname:

```
namespace = Ext.Loader.getPrefix(className) || match[1];
namespaceAndModule = namespace + '.' + module + '.'
```

But For each view, store, model its controller creates getter passing name into getStore, getView, getModel function

```
if (!this[fn]) {
    this[fn] = Ext.Function.pass(this['get' + type], [ref], this);
}
```

The getStore function that getter is passed into returns application store:

```
getStore: function(name) {
    return this.application.getStore(name);
},
```

Application itself  uses getModuleClassName to resolve class name

```
getModuleClassName: function(name, module) {

    if (name.indexOf('.') !== -1 && (Ext.ClassManager.isCreated(name) || Ext.Loader.isAClassNameWithAKnownPrefix(name))) {
        return name;
    } else {
        return this.name + '.' + module + '.' + name;
    }
}
```

So if there is fully qualified class name with known prefix it will return name only otherwise class name will be built using `this.name` which is application name so using `stores:['Test']` will point to `A.store.Test`.

I am thinking about writing an override but I am afraid that it will break other things.